# MessageBox.Show() with Yes or No confirmation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

MessageBox.Show() with Yes or No confirmation dialog box displayed in Windows Forms Application..Now I want to Shows as same as in aspx.cs page...Which namespace i added here?
If i reference System.Windows.Forms namespace..I get an error?

This code for Windows Application..

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation",
  messageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
 if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
  //...
 else if (result == DialogResult.No)
 //...
else
  //...
```

But in aspx page..how can i write?

Comment: I don't quite get it. *Where* do you want your Message Box to be shown? In user's browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net

Comment: where exactly you want to show your messagebox

Comment: i want to display this message for Gridview Updation,when user click on Update,then it check the database values ,if exits or not with confirmation messages..

Comment: please edit your question and add this portion so the question would be more obvious

Comment: I have edit my answer, please review it also, where do you do your update inside the gridView itself or outside the griView, I mean where is the update button

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ScriptManager to inject a javascript code from code behind from the server

like this

```
var script = "alert(\'this is a message box\');";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "messageBox", script, true);
```

but when you need to show something like '*are you sure?*' message box style with yes,no you need to use [confirm messageBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm)

any way please show when and where you need to show your message

**EDIT**

If you want to do this you will have two solutions

1. you will use ajax so you can display message to the user without doing postback
2. or you do your postback and do the check in the server and after that display messagebox to the user by using ***ScriptManager***

either way you can't use a native windows message box by calling the winForms API to do this in the browser, let the browser do this job instead of you

**EDIT 2**

If you are using DataSource with the GridView you can use the Event On Updating to check the user edit before you do the actual update and if you accept it you can do the update otherwise you can reject it

```
OnUpdating="SqlDataSource1_Updating"
```

[You can review the event from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: inside gridview control

Comment: as I have told you if you want to tell the user about the result after checking the database you you need to do it from the server not from the html page after that you can display a message to the user telling him the result by using Scriptmanager as described in the answer

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by using system.windows.forms reference in your code. but it wont work fine when you have hosted your asp site. using java script is a better idea

Comment: here,i want to display this message for Gridview Updation,when user click on Update,then it check the database values ,if exits or not..

Comment: you can write a javascript script function there and call it using 
Page.RegisterStartupScript
so when you update is clicked, you should call this function and get response

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a message box in aspx.cs page. Its only for Windows form.

But in javascript, you can create something like MessageBox

For YesNo :

```
var ok = confirm("Do you want to delete this ?");
```

For just Ok:

```
alert("Hi");
```

In the `ok` variable, you'll have true or false based on user input.

Even if it is possible, *which I don't think will be*, its a bad idea to do so.

Of course, after adding the appropriate dll, you *might* get the Intellisense, but of no use.