# Why is Opera executing javascript from a stackoverflow comment?

Tags: javascript, opera

I noticed a strange opera activity, specifically when I killed browser with open tabs and started it again it executed  js from this page: [display messagebox in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net)
And I saw alert 'Login successful'

This happens every time I 'force restart' opera.

How is it possible ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qWTG.jpg]

I am using Opera 24.0.1558.61 Win8.1 x64

Comment: Wow, this is a huge security flaw man. Opera developers are dumb people if they allow this to happen.

Comment: happens in I.E8 too , only error'd executing the js

Comment: I can't reproduce using Opera 12.16 on OSX

Comment: Probably belongs on SuperUser, not SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was not caused by Opera at all. It was a malfunctioning third party extension that breaks on this website. The same extension breaks in the same way in other supported browsers when given the same conditions.

If you uncover an exploitable security issue in Opera, you can report it confidentially to the Opera bug tracking system. We'll be happy to credit you for responsible disclosure if we find it to be exploitable.

Comment: We have contacted the author of the extension, and they have issued a fix here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickable-links/mgamelhnfokapndfdodnmfiningckjia/details