# restrict when to execute database update

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code for stock inventory management. I have made it so that if the stock is *less than or equal* to `500`, it will show a `MessageBox`, but it will process the order.

but if the variable (p <= 0)  then ideally the order should not be processed.

but under the button the orders are being processed even if the stock is below 0.

i need to restrict when these orders are processed and the updates are made to the DB.

```
    //Creating a connection to my database using the connection string
    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    //preparing a query which will take away the values entered in the textboxes from the stock count currently in the database table a rows in the database 
    // http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/error-when-trying-reduce-a-certain-number-from-the-database

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfStickers= AmtOfStickers - " + this.txtStickers.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfLids= AmtOfLids - " + this.txtLids.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfSJars= AmtOfSJars - " + this.txtSmallJars.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfLJars= AmtOfLJars - " + this.txtLargeJars.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderDate, CustomerID, LidNo, StickerNo, LJarNo, SJarNo) values('" + this.txtDate.Text + "','" + this.txtId.Text + "','"
       + this.txtLids.Text + "','" + this.txtStickers.Text + "','" + this.txtLargeJars.Text + "','" + this.txtSmallJars.Text + "')", con);



    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();








        SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd5.CommandText = "Select * from [StockTable]";
        cmd5.Connection = con;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd5);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Label12.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfStickers"] + "";
        Label13.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfSJars"] + "";
        Label14.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfLJars"] + "";
        Label15.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfLids"] + "";

        int p = Convert.ToInt32(Label12.Text);
        int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(Label13.Text);
        int p2 = Convert.ToInt32(Label14.Text);
        int p3 = Convert.ToInt32(Label15.Text);

        if (p <= 0)
        {



            smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
            username.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            password.Text = "***";
            from.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            to.Text ="molagahoney@gmail.com";
            subject.Text = "Stock is Low";
            body.Text = "Hi Jerry,  your sticker stock is 0,  please restock soon to continue taking orders.  Kay Oates.";


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

            SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);

            Client.Port = 587;

            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

            Client.EnableSsl = true;
            Client.Send(mail);

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net messagebox dispalying mail sent
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Your Sticker Stock level is 0 and therefore cannot process this order. A Mail has been Sent notifying the manager.  ')</script>");


        }


        else if (p >= 1 && p <= 500)
        {



            smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
            username.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            password.Text = "***";
            from.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            to.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            subject.Text = "Stock is Low";
            body.Text = "Hi Jerry <br> your small jar stock is low, <br> please restock soon to continue taking orders. <br> Kay Oates.";


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

            SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);

            Client.Port = 587;

            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

            Client.EnableSsl = true;
            Client.Send(mail);
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net messagebox dispalying mail sent
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Your sticker stock level is low and therefore a Mail has been Sent notifying the manager. ')</script>");
            Server.Transfer("orderDisplay.aspx");
        }
```

Therefore I think I need to make the first statement if p is between 1 and 500.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: `if (p <= 500 && p > 0) {`... Take a moment to rename your variables. Give them meaningful names. Your future self will thank me for this.

Answer (score 1):

zero is less than 500 and thats why it only runs the first statement. If you put the less than zero first it will work as expected:

```
if(p <= 0)
{
    // some code
} else if (p <= 500) {
    // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (p >= 1 and p <= 500) { first block code }
else if (p <= 0) { second block code }
```

or better

```
if (p <= 0) { second block code }
else if (p <= 500) { first block code }
```

Comment: thank you that worked. i just have one more question. if P=0 i dont want the button to execute to update the database table. do you know how if p <= 0 i could stop these commands from executing?

Comment: you're welcome. I don't prefer to use too much "<=" or ">=", so, can try :
if (p < 1) { } else if (p <= 500). Please don't forget to mark the answer as a solution

Comment: yes that works. but also under this button i have to update the database, but i only want to update the DB when the stock is greater than 0, at the moment it is still updating the DB even if the stock is under 0 and processing orders even though there is no stock to create the orders

Comment: If i'm right, probably you save the dates outside "IF" statement. Try to put the code which save in DB into IF

Comment: i edited my code above if you want to take a look at it please. it may be more clear to you what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just looking for this:

```
if (p <= 500 && p > 0)
```

Otherwise your `else` would never be entered because all values less than 0 are also less than 500.

Alternatively, you could swap the conditions and test the more constrained one first:

```
if (p <= 0)
{
    //...
}
else if (p <= 500)
{
    //...
}
```