# update Database if variable is true only

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, web-deployment

This skips right to the fourth if statement, even if the amount requested is more than the available amount.

it worked with the first two, but when i added the third and fourth if statement it doesn't seem to read the third at all and skips to preform the fourth and goes into - inventory.

any help is welcomed.

here is my code all under the one button.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{




   // Creating a connection to my database using the connection string
    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    //preparing a query which will take away the values entered in the textboxes from the stock count currently in the database table a rows in the database 
     http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/error-when-trying-reduce-a-certain-number-from-the-database

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfStickers= AmtOfStickers - " + this.txtStickers.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfLids= AmtOfLids - " + this.txtLids.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfSJars= AmtOfSJars - " + this.txtSmallJars.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockTable set AmtOfLJars= AmtOfLJars - " + this.txtLargeJars.Text + ";", con);
    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OrderDetails(OrderDate, CustomerID, LidNo, StickerNo, LJarNo, SJarNo) values('" + this.txtDate.Text + "','" + this.txtId.Text + "','"
       + this.txtLids.Text + "','" + this.txtStickers.Text + "','" + this.txtLargeJars.Text + "','" + this.txtSmallJars.Text + "')", con);






    SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd5.CommandText = "Select * from [StockTable]";
    cmd5.Connection = con;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd5);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    Label12.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfStickers"] + "";
    Label13.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfSJars"] + "";
    Label14.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfLJars"] + "";
    Label15.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AmtOfLids"] + "";


    int p = Convert.ToInt32(Label12.Text);
    int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(Label13.Text);
    int p2 = Convert.ToInt32(Label14.Text);
    int p3 = Convert.ToInt32(Label15.Text);

    int ammountRequested = Convert.ToInt32(txtStickers.Text);
int ammountAvailable = Convert.ToInt32(Label12.Text);

int ammountRequestedlids = Convert.ToInt32(txtLids.Text);
int ammountAvailablelids = Convert.ToInt32(Label13.Text);

if (ammountRequested > ammountAvailable)
        {



            smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
            username.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            password.Text = "***";
            from.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            to.Text ="molagahoney@gmail.com";
            subject.Text = "Stock is Low";
            body.Text = "Hi Jerry,  your sticker stock is 0,  please restock soon to continue taking orders.  Kay Oates.";


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

            SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);

            Client.Port = 587;

            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

            Client.EnableSsl = true;
            Client.Send(mail);

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net messagebox dispalying mail sent
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Your Sticker Stock level is 0 and therefore cannot process this order. A Mail has been Sent notifying the manager.  ')</script>");


        }


else if (ammountRequested < ammountAvailable)
        {


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

            smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
            username.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            password.Text = "****";
            from.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            to.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            subject.Text = "Stock is Low";
            body.Text = "Hi Jerry <br> your small jar stock is low, <br> please restock soon to continue taking orders. <br> Kay Oates.";


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

            SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);

            Client.Port = 587;

            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

            Client.EnableSsl = true;
            Client.Send(mail);
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net messagebox dispalying mail sent
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Your sticker stock level is low and therefore a Mail has been Sent notifying the manager. ')</script>");
            Server.Transfer("orderDisplay.aspx");
        }
else if (ammountRequestedlids > ammountAvailablelids)
        {
            smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
            username.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            password.Text = "****";
            from.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            to.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            subject.Text = "Stock is Low";
            body.Text = "Hi Jerry <br> your small jar stock is 0, <br> please restock soon to continue taking orders. <br> Kay Oates.";


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

            SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);

            Client.Port = 587;

            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

            Client.EnableSsl = true;
            Client.Send(mail);
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net messagebox dispalying mail sent
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Your Small Jar Stock level is 0 and therefore a Mail has been Sent. <br> unfortunatley ')</script>");

        }
else if (ammountRequestedlids < ammountAvailablelids)
        {

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

            smtp.Text = "smtp.gmail.com";
            username.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            password.Text = "****";
            from.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            to.Text = "molagahoney@gmail.com";
            subject.Text = "Stock is Low";
            body.Text = "Hi Jerry <br> your small jar stock is low, <br> please restock soon to continue taking orders. <br> Kay Oates.";


            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

            SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text);

            Client.Port = 587;

            Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

            Client.EnableSsl = true;
            Client.Send(mail);
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/display-messagebox-in-asp-net messagebox dispalying mail sent
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >alert('Your small jar stock level is low and therefore a Mail has been Sent notifying the manager. ')</script>");
            Server.Transfer("orderDisplay.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your issue is that the `if(p <= 0)` statement is never entered even when you think `p` is 0?

Comment: Well I assume the order is placed when executing the SqlCommands, no? - So you would have to wrap all 'ExecuteNonQuery' statements in an if block (`if p>0`).

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562632/restrict-when-to-execute-database-update)? Furthermore if you do not know how to create basic `if` statements then I would recommend going through a couple of turorials first...

Comment: You may as well wrap the whole thing in that if statement, since there is no reason to run any of those queries or open a connection or anything. Also, don't forget that SqlCommand needs to be disposed.

Comment: @VDWWD this was a question in which was originally different, and i then edited it to change the question in which nobody was viewing, so created a new one.

Comment: FYI, there is a case - just between 0 and 1, where neither if case will apply. 0.5 is neither <=0 nor >=1. It is unlikely to happen with integers, but if you ever reuse this code for float it might become an issue. The if statements themself look okay (no accidental semikolon). So that primarily leaves the value of P being not what you expect. The whole programm looks odd, however: No using block for the Connection. You build the query from string connaction. Ideally the button should not even be enabeled when teh input is lower then 1. You use Convert when you should be using parse.

Comment: @amura.cxg yes if p <=0 i dont not want to update the DB

Comment: @user1304444 i have edited the code to wrap it in the if statement, when i ran this, when the value was below 0, it skipped the first if statement and went straight to the second.

Comment: @carol your solution of putting the Sql commands in the else statement should work. It sounds like you expect `p` to equal 0 but it's not. Have you tried putting a breakpoint to ensure it's actually 0 when you expect it to be?

Comment: @Christopher you're correct 0.5 would bypass both if statements, however `p` is an `int` and cannot be 0.5. See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4W7Sq5)

Comment: @amura.cxg i edited the above code to wrap them into the if statements, but it skips the if statement if (P <=0) and goes straight to the else if statement and executes even if the value is 0 or below.

Comment: @carol if `p` is 0 it would go into that the first part of the if statement, we can be sure of that. What this means is that you think `p` is 0, but it's not. Try adding `Console.WriteLine(p);` before the if statement and see what `p` equals. What does `Label12` show? Maybe you have the wrong label.

Comment: @amura.cxg okay so i just ran it, and if p = 0 it will run but if p < 0 ( say 5) but 15 materials are needed, it will preform and go into -10 in the sock DB. what i was trying to do was if there was not enough stock to create to order to decline the order. also label 12, is just on the form invisible and is the value of p so it is easier to read from p from a label

Comment: @carol I think you might be confused,  `p` will not be less than 0 if it's 5. Are you trying to strop someone from ordering more stocks than are available? Eg. If they want 15 but there are only 5 available an update doesn't happen

Comment: @amura.cxg yes that exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: Your code isn't doing that, all it's doing is comparing `p` (the amount available) to 0. You need to compare the amount requested to `p`. Eg `if (ammountRequested > p) { /*Send error message*/ }

Comment: @amura.cxg thank you soo much! i really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Actually the right place to do this comparision in, is the DB query. If you only check validity in the Programm, you **will** run into Race Conditions (the value in the DB was changed to below what you need between last load and sending the order).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of discussion it sounds like your actual issue is that you want to make sure a user can't request more stocks than are available. You have a lot code and it's not clear where you would get all the information from but here is a simple template of how you could go about this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the values from SQL etc.

    int ammountRequested = //This needs to be pulled from somewhere
    int ammountAvailable = Convert.ToInt32(Label12.Text);

    if(ammountRequested > ammountAvailable)
    {
        //Send the error message
    }
    else
    {
        //Do the updates
        //Send the message
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Looking at your updated code it looks like you're confused about `if` statements. I suggest reading through [this tutorial](https://www.dotnetperls.com/if).

It also sounds like you don't have a clear idea on what workflow you want your code to follow. Before you write more code you should take some time to consider different situations and how you want to handle them. Ask yourself questions like: what happens if the user requests multiple stocks but one isn't available and the other is? How should to code handle that situation?

There are a lot of talented users on SO and many of them could answer these questions for you given a good problem description. But that's the point of SO, we're here to help with programming problems so you can learn to program. If after thinking about the workflow and understanding `if` statements you still aren't clear about something, write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're stuck on and we'll help you out. And if you haven't read through the [Asking a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: The check must be done in the DatabaseQuery doing the Updating/addition of hte Order. Doing it only programm side will run you head first into race conditions if more then one user/client can place orders.

Comment: @amura.cxg  this is working for the first set, but when i go to add this to the second set of if statement it doesnt work. it keeps bypassing the third if statement and going to fourth.  i will edit the code to show you

Comment: @amura.cxg i do understand if statements, just do not understand why it works for the first set and not the second as it is the same code changed to fit the second set of if statements....