# how to access master page properties from aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, messagebox

```
lblTitle = ((Default)_page.Master).messageBoxTitle;
lblError = ((Default)_page.Master).messageBoxMsg;
btn1 = ((Default)_page.Master).button1;
btn2 = ((Default)_page.Master).button2;
btn3 = ((Default)_page.Master).button3;
imgIcon = ((Default)_page.Master).messageBoxIcon;
```

I do not understand this part of the code that comes out of a discussion.
I start in C #, can someone help me.
Thank you in advance.

[How can I display a messagebox in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/how-can-i-display-a-messagebox-in-asp-net)

Comment: you would have to use Javascript. ASP.NET is a server-side technology.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a page, that use a master page and you wish to access some of their properties - you need to declare it as you know that it is. For example, let say that this is the master page

```
public partial class main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string cSomeString ;


}
```

and this is the aspx page that have the above master and you wish to access their properties.

```
public partial class OtherPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // access on the master page the cSomeString
    ((main)Master).cSomeString ;
}
```