# How to display an error message if dropdown list is null

Tags: vb.net, dropdown

I have a dropdown that displays nothing. If I hit the save button and nothing is displayed I want an error message stating something has to be selected

I've tried if ddl.POApprover.text = "" then display the message but that doesn't display

```
If ddlPOApprover.Text = "" And (Session("UserGroup") = 13) Then
            MsgBox("Error: An Approver must be provided before you can save")
            blnValidation = False
        End If
```

I want the error to come up when I hit save but it doesn't

Comment: I see you are using `Session` in there. Does that mean it's an ASP.NET program? If so, the message box will appear on the server, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: ...but you could use [How can I display a messagebox in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/how-can-i-display-a-messagebox-in-asp-net)

Comment: Either way, you need to set [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) and correct the problems it points out for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's `If ddlPOApprover.SelectedValue` not `.Text`

Answer (score 1):

A Combobox has an array from 0 to numberOfItems -1. 
whenever there is nothing selected, it's index is -1
so you can check `if ddlPOApprover.selectedindex < 0 then` no item has been chosen

Edit: i also want you to try replacing `And` with `AndAlso` like:
 `If ddlPOApprover.Text = "" AndAlso (Session("UserGroup") = 13) Then` 
would it still give you an error? if not then you can choose either my main answer or leave it and just change `And` to `AndAlso`