# Is there a reason why MessageBox.Show() causes my applications to freeze?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently building an ASP.NET web application and I've noticed that using MessageBox.Show() will often cause my entire application to freeze and require a restart. Is this normal behaviour?
It doesn't happen all the time and especially seems to happen when it is called before the entire page has loaded.

This never happened in winform applications.

Is there perhaps a better way to send notifications to the user?

Sorry if the answer is obvious I'm still fairly new to all this.

Comment: MessageBox, in a _web_ application? Is this WebForms (no idea if that has message boxes, but _certainly_ MVC doesn't) Can you [edit] your post with a [mre]?

Comment: Wait, you want to show a message box on the Web Server? No-one will see it there.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196381/how-can-i-display-a-messagebox-in-asp-net

Comment: @gunr2171 Just create a new ASP.NET MVC project and in the HomeController.cs Index method just put: MessageBox.Show("Hello");

Comment: @KlausGütter So you mean to say that the messagebox will only appear on the server side and not the user?

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of `MessageBox`? It doesn't make sense to use MessageBox with a web application.

Comment: @gunr2171 System.Windows.MessageBox, but nevermind it's clear now that i should not use this in a webapplication. I'll go look into other ways of pushing out notifications.

Answer (score 2):

This was interesting. I have added reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly and then used the following code:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    return View();
}
```

When I ran the application the message box is come up. After click on <kbd>OK</kbd> the browser is opening:

[image]

This is working that way because when I run the application I already having the Windows UI session. But usually when the ASP.NET MVC application is running on the server the IIS has no resources to the UI interaction. So I suppose your application will freeze or abnormally terminated.

Comment: That should reproduce what the OP is seeing - a message box comes up on the server which halts the thread until it is closed.

Comment: I put this at the top of the page controller to get it working: 
`using System.Windows`

But after reading some comments I'm starting to doubt if the end user will see the MessageBox and if it's not just something that will only show the MessageBox on the server side.

Comment: @gunr2171 The freeze I'm talking about is not just the page being halted, because after dismissing the MessageBox the whole app is still frozen. Reloading the page or going back to home won't work either. 
I'll have to restart the whole thing over again.

Comment: @gunr2171: Yes, exactly. I already added the remark. This is exactly the same case like trying to show a message from a Windows service. Anyway call to the `MessageBox.Show()` is performing on the server side, not the client of course.

Comment: @Merv: Of course, there is no reason to use GUI related function in the ASP.NET MVC application. For the debug purpose you can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(...);` or any logger tools, like the [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).